# ITypeLib: GetLibAttr and ReleaseTLibAttr

Tags: c++, com, win32com, typelib

Problem: The `ITypeLib::GetLibAttr()` method allocates a new `TLIBATTR` struct, requiring me to call `ITypeLib::ReleaseTLibAttr()`? This makes the code too verbose for my taste, and it has the potential for memory leaks if overlooked.

If I cache the result, then call `ReleaseTLibAttr()`, are there any side effects or potential pitfalls when using the cached value?

---

The TLIBATTR struct is just a set of simple values:

```
typedef struct tagTLIBATTR
{
    GUID guid;
    LCID lcid;
    SYSKIND syskind;
    WORD wMajorVerNum;
    WORD wMinorVerNum;
    WORD wLibFlags;
} TLIBATTR;
```

There are no members which are themselves dynamically allocated. Perhaps that is subject to change?

---

I wrote a simple helper method to prevent the need to call `ReleaseTLibAttr()`.

```cpp
HRESULT MyGetLibAttr(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, TLIBATTR *pTLibAttr)
{
    TLIBATTR *pTLibAttrTemp;
    HRESULT hr = pTypeLib->GetLibAttr( &pTLibAttrTemp );
    if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        memcpy( pTLibAttr, pTLibAttrTemp, sizeof(TLIBATTR) );
        pTypeLib->ReleaseTLibAttr( pTLibAttrTemp );
    }
    return hr;
}

void main()
{
    ITypeLib *pTypeLib;
    HRESULT hr = LoadTypeLibEx( ... , &pTypeLib);
    if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        TLIBATTR libAttr;
        hr = MyGetLibAttr( pTypeLib, &libAttr );
        if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
        {
            // Now we have a TLIBATTR object that we don't have to free.
        }
        pTypeLib->Release();
    }
}
```

On a scale of 1 to 10, how future proof is `MyGetLibAttr()` (error handling aside)? Are there any side effects to using the cached result?

I realize there is a small performance hit (the extra call to `memcpy()`), but the bigger concern for us is code maintenance and memory leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface method was designed like this back in 1996 because they did not want to lose the opportunity to add members to the structure.  That did not in fact happen, TLIBATTR has been stable for 19 years.  And will never change again, Microsoft has moved away from the .tlb format and is now using the .winmd format.

If it makes you feel any better, the .NET Framework [also copies the structure](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/typelibconverter.cs,762bcb79ece4ddb3).

Answer (score 1):

There are nothing wrong with you code.
You can check the source code of GetLibAttr at https://github.com/alexhenrie/wine/blob/master/dlls/oleaut32/typelib.c - ITypeLib2_fnGetLibAttr.
Since you have loaded TypeLib, then guid, lcid, syskind, wMajorVerNum, wMinorVerNum, wLibFlags can not be changed till next load TLB file and only in case if that file was changed.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Just curious, is there a reason you linked the alexhenrie/wine repo as opposed to the wine-mirror/wine repo? Not a big deal, just curious. On the surface, this one seems more "official": https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/dlls/oleaut32/typelib.c

Comment: @skataben. Yes you are right, **official** link is more correct. There is no special reason for alexherie link here. It was just a first link to the wine project that i found.